# Rails multiple select on array attribute not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following isn't displaying a multiple select in Firefox:

`<%= f.select :days, days_of_week_for_select, { selected: '0' }, multple: 'true' %>`

The html produced is:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-10">
<select multple="true" rows="5" name="series[days]" id="series_days">
<option value="0">Sunday</option>
<option value="1">Monday</option>
<option value="2">Tuesday</option>
<option value="3">Wednesday</option>
<option value="4">Thursday</option>
<option value="5">Friday</option>
<option value="6">Saturday</option>
</select>   
</div>
```

And the helper:

```
  def days_of_week_for_select
    array = Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index.map { |day, ind| [day, ind] }
    options_for_select array
  end
```

The select list is a normal, single select, not multiple.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `multiple: true` instead of `multple: true`. You are missing a character in that option :)